# Android SQLite database cursor iteration error

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a SQLite database and when i try to loop through all of the records, I get an error during iteration. I have about 900 records or so in this database and when it gets to record 217, (the i integer gets to 217, for debugging purposes) I get an error from CursorWindow tag stating:

"Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 7 columns."

Here is the code for iteration through the records:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + SONG_TABLE_NAME;
Cursor c = null;
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //loop through all rows and add to list
    if (c!= null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println(i);
            i++;

            //Do stuff...

          } while (c.moveToNext());
      }
  } finally {
      if (c != null)
          c.close();
  }
```

Thank you.

Update:
Data is about song information. Song name, artist, album stored as strings. Album art stored as byte array (blob in database).

```
songNo=210 albumName=Long Live the Kings songName=Proud To Be A Stoner artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@42236c50
songNo=211 albumName=Koast II Koast songName=Party artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@422ae498
songNo=212 albumName=Koast II Koast songName=Where's the Weed At artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@4231ac18
songNo=213 albumName=High Society songName=First Class artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@422ae498
songNo=214 albumName=Cloud Nine songName=Pass It Around artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@422d7be8
songNo=215 albumName=Rollin' Stoned songName=Rest of My Life artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@423451c0
songNo=216 albumName=Rollin' Stoned songName=Tangerine Sky artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@42378ef8
songNo=217 albumName=Hidden Stash III [Disc 1] songName=Still Smokin artistName=Kottonmouth Kings art=[B@423acc30
songNo=218 albumName=Get Buck in Here songName=Get Buck in Here artistName=DJ Felli Fel art=[B@422ae498
songNo=219 albumName=Best Day Ever songName=Get Up! artistName=Mac Miller art=[B@422f3138
songNo=220 albumName=K.I.D.S songName=Knock Knock artistName=Mac Miller art=[B@4231ba98
```

Now when I ran it, i got an error on getting record 218. Here is the relevant logcat.

```
03-24 12:57:22.799: I/System.out(15710): 210
03-24 12:57:22.809: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 497K, 17% free 9941K/11928K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
03-24 12:57:22.809: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:57:22.809: I/System.out(15710): 211
03-24 12:57:22.829: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 236K, 17% free 9941K/11928K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-24 12:57:22.839: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 478K, 17% free 9941K/11928K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-24 12:57:22.839: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:57:22.919: W/CursorWindow(15710): Window is full: requested allocation 169783 bytes, free space 72617 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-24 12:57:22.919: I/System.out(15710): 212
03-24 12:57:22.929: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 478K, 17% free 9941K/11928K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-24 12:57:22.949: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 433K, 17% free 9941K/11928K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-24 12:57:22.949: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:57:22.949: I/System.out(15710): 213
03-24 12:57:22.959: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 434K, 17% free 9942K/11928K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-24 12:57:22.979: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 448K, 17% free 9942K/11928K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-24 12:57:22.979: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:57:23.049: W/CursorWindow(15710): Window is full: requested allocation 447936 bytes, free space 172276 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-24 12:57:23.049: I/System.out(15710): 214
03-24 12:57:23.069: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 449K, 17% free 9942K/11928K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-24 12:57:23.069: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:57:23.139: W/CursorWindow(15710): Window is full: requested allocation 447936 bytes, free space 411808 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-24 12:57:23.159: W/CursorWindow(15710): Window is full: requested allocation 2974082 bytes, free space 1223747 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-24 12:57:41.767: I/System.out(15710): record number: 215215
03-24 12:57:44.460: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 332K, 17% free 9942K/11928K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
03-24 12:57:46.342: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 437K, 17% free 9942K/11928K, paused 25ms, total 26ms
03-24 12:57:46.572: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:57:48.224: I/System.out(15710): 216
03-24 12:57:52.478: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 437K, 17% free 9943K/11928K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
03-24 12:57:54.290: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:57:57.333: I/System.out(15710): 217
03-24 12:58:05.340: D/dalvikvm(15710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 415K, 17% free 9943K/11928K, paused 24ms, total 25ms
03-24 12:58:08.363: D/skia(15710): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
03-24 12:58:12.087: W/CursorWindow(15710): Window is full: requested allocation 2974082 bytes, free space 594167 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-24 12:58:12.087: W/CursorWindow(15710): Window is full: requested allocation 2974082 bytes, free space 2096591 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
03-24 12:58:13.338: I/System.out(15710): 218
03-24 12:58:15.120: E/CursorWindow(15710): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 7 columns.
03-24 12:58:16.772: E/CursorWindow(15710): Failed to read row 0, column 3 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 7 columns.
03-24 12:58:24.679: E/CursorWindow(15710): Failed to read row 0, column 2 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 7 columns.
03-24 12:59:15.048: E/CursorWindow(15710): Failed to read row 0, column 6 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 7 columns.
03-24 12:59:16.390: E/CursorWindow(15710): Failed to read row 0, column 5 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 7 columns.
03-24 12:59:40.583: W/dalvikvm(15710): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4189cba8)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): Process: com.allengauch.mediaplayer, PID: 15710
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:399) 
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at com.allengauch.mediaplayer.SongsDataBase.getAllSongs(SongsDataBase.java:225) 
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at com.allengauch.mediaplayer.SongsActivity$WorkerThread.doInBackground(SongsActivity.java:252)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at com.allengauch.mediaplayer.SongsActivity$WorkerThread.doInBackground(SongsActivity.java:1) 
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-24 12:59:40.663: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): ... 4 more
```

Comment: can you post your full logcat along with the data at ids 210-220.

this will help us co-relate

Comment: Also, just realized it is erroring on 218 because I set i = 1 instead of 0, as in original post. So it is still erroring on the same spot.

Comment: please add your FutureTask,java

also indicate line number 355 in it.
The exception is there

Comment: Well the FutureTask is in java.util, thats not my code. But the reason the async task failed is because getting the cursor trying to retrieve record number 218 failed. It also is not the data in record 218 because I deleted files 210-220 and then retried it and i still get the error in the same position.

Comment: post SongsDatabase.java and indicate line number 225

Comment: also post WorkerThread if you have, and indicate line# 252 of your SongsActivity.java

Comment: Hey thanks for all your help but I figured it out. It turns out one of the data fields (art) was a rather large file (2 mb or so) so the cursor was threw an error. With images of small size, it works fine.

Comment: glad that you did it by yourself